# What can be done with people posting offtopic questions on a regular basis?

Tags: discussion, moderator-abilities, off-topic

Suppose a person comes to SO and starts posting questions, half of them being offtopic. Many of those offtopic questions are closed as offtopic, but the user posts more offtopic questions after previous ones were closed. Now, when pointed to this fact (as part of the correct answer to one of his offtopic question), this user downvotes my answer yet makes no further actions regarding any of his offtopic questions.

In general, what can be done (technically and from rules point of view) with such person?

Comment: How do you know it was that user downvoting your answer? :)

Comment: @radp by mathing in time the change in his reputation (-1) to time of his downvote.

Comment: But nevertheless, it would be nice if one of the moderators or somebody from the team could shed some official light on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can either flag the question with your downvoted answer for moderator attention and describe there your problem there or you can send an email via the contact us links you find at the bottom of each page.

I think it is up to the moderators and the team to take care.

Comment: As I wrote (yet @radp removed that part), this is more a theoretical question - I am mostly interested in general rules regarding people posting offtopic questions all the time. I don't care about the downvote itself.

Comment: @Eugenie I attempted to remove any hint of a person being behind this. If you don't agree with the edit feel free to click the "rollback" button :)

Comment: @radp not sure if I left any traces in the original message :). Nevermind, let's keep it as it is now.